# Concurrency issue data corruption asyncio python-can locking/queues - nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, python-asyncio, can-bus, python-can

I am at the end of a very long journey...

Here is the long story if you are interested.
https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can/issues/1336

Sorry for the incredibly long code snippet but I am not sure where I am going wrong so I thought more is more.

The code is as follows `request_inst()` requests instrumentation data using the dict `request_info` from an MCU, the MCU responds and this is picked up by the `listener`. `obtain_message()` creates a future with which to store `all_data` that is yielded from the `listener` with `msg = await reader.get_message()`. I attempt to structure this process with `lock`. `store_data()` is where I store the response data from the MCU, this is a dict called `all_data`. `all_data` when printed outside of the `listener` appears with zero values as shown below. The purpose of the code is to make `all_data` available outside of the event loop but currently even with this implementation I cannot get `all_data` to appear without zero values showing up in the dict.

```
import asyncio
import can
from can.notifier import MessageRecipient
from typing import List

freq = 0.0003

# this is the respond ids and the and the parameter ids of the data
# stored data is suppose to fill up the None with a value
all_data = {268439810: {16512: [None], 16513: [None], 16514: [None], 16515: [None]},
            268444162: {16512: [None], 16513: [None], 16514: [None], 16515: [None]}}

request_info = {286326784: {16512, 16513, 16514, 16515},
                287440896: {16512, 16513, 16514, 16515}}

# all the request ids in that have been configured
cm4_read_ids = [286326784, 287440896]

# all the response ids in that have been configured
mcu_respond_ids = [268439810, 268444162]

# finds arb id and pid and logs the data from the message
# async def store_data(arb_id, msg_data, msg_dlc):
async def store_data(msg: can.Message, lock):
    pid = int.from_bytes(msg.data[0:2], 'little')
    arb_id = msg.arbitration_id
    if arb_id in mcu_respond_ids:
        async with lock:
            if msg.dlc == 5:
                all_data[arb_id][pid][0] = int.from_bytes(msg.data[2:4], 'little', signed=False)
            elif msg.dlc == 7:
                all_data[arb_id][pid][0] = int.from_bytes(msg.data[2:6], 'little', signed=False)
    return all_data

async def request_inst(bus: can.Bus):
    print('Request inst active')
    while True:
        for key in request_info:
            for val in request_info[key]:
                pid = int(val)
                pidbytes = pid.to_bytes(2, 'little')
                msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=key, data=pidbytes)
                bus.send(msg)
                await asyncio.sleep(freq)
                # await store_data(reader)

async def message_obtain(reader: can.AsyncBufferedReader, lock):
    print('Started it the get message process')
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
        msg = await reader.get_message()
        future = await store_data(msg, lock)
        async with lock:

            print('This is the future')
            print(future)

async def main() -> None:
    with can.Bus(
            interface="socketcan", channel="can0", receive_own_messages=True
    ) as bus:
        # Create Notifier with an explicit loop to use for scheduling of callbacks
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        reader = can.AsyncBufferedReader()
        lock = asyncio.Lock()

        listeners: List[MessageRecipient] = [reader]

        notifier = can.Notifier(bus, listeners, loop=loop)

        try:
            task1 = asyncio.create_task(request_inst(bus))
            task2 = asyncio.create_task(message_obtain(reader, lock))
            await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:

            notifier.stop()
            bus.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The issue I am seeing is that even on this cut down one page wonder I am seeing what I believe to be concurrency issues.

As you can see I have tried locking but still I am seeing these zero values appear in `all_data` See below where pid 16514's balue becomes 0 when the messages being returned by the MCU are not zero.

n.b. the output below where the incorrect data is shown is the output from `print(future)`

[image]

The real value should never be 0 as it is a measured value.

```
b6 = (1016872961).to_bytes(4, 'little')
struct.unpack('<f', b6)
(0.01907348819077015,)
```

Am I doing anything very stupid? It feels like I am not accessing the data in the listener correctly despite using lock when `all_data` is being modified.

If I print from the `listeners` the data is always correct even when `all_data` is returning 0 values.

If anyone is able to help me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `i am here at the end of a log journey` , `here is the code` `Am I doing anything very stupid or is there are better way to do this.` **DO WHAT EXACTLY** ? it's good to give some backstory to your question, people are likely not going to read your code to try to figure out what you want to do, nor do they visit a github to potentially .. read more code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I have added a description.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok ok ok, it turns out I was doing something **really** silly. I was using nested dictionaries to store data about different ids but the keys were the same. After some investigation using `id(id1[some_pid1])` and `id(id2[some_pid1])` I discovered the keys had the same memory address.

```
data_dict = {id1: {some_pid1: value, some_pid2: value},
             id2: {some_pid1: value, some_pid2: value}}
```

This appeared to all that it was a race condition but actually I was just writing zeros (which turned out to be forced from the MCU) to the wrong id because it shared a key with the other id.

**Whoops**

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was not software related and the zeros were real. Every day is a learning day!

This is a PCAN image of the highlighted send and a response shown at the top.

[image]

EDIT: Confirmed MCU response issue - looks like the firmware on the MCU. My Rigol wouldn't trigger on the ID so I had to 1/8 video and then screen shot that to catch it in the act. You can see the response is all 7 bytes of nothing.

[image]